# Excel Power Query to check duplicates in large datasets

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

So in a nutshell the problem is, that I have 3.0 million of different itemIDs in one dataset (CSV for example) and 1.0 million itemIDs in another dataset.

What would be the most convenient way to find out all of the duplicates? In basic excel it would be an easy task, but there's too much rows to be imported. Would Power Query be helpful for my problem?

I was thinking that if you could extract the first itemIDs to a data model column A, then extract the second dataset into column B, and then write a formula to column C which checks whether the individual itemID listed in column B exists in somewhere in column A, and if yes then the value in column C would be 1 (else 0).

After doing that I could make a pivot table from that datamodel where column C value 1 is used as a filter and column B itemID are presented in the rows.

Sorry for the unclear explanation, but could someone advice me if this is a good idea how to check the duplicates or if you have any better idea.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Combine the datasets into a single column; then remove duplicates.

Comment: I believe that would be in the `Remove Rows` selection in the UI which invokes the `Table.Distinct` function.